# Error in Remote Calabash Server: 'Connection refused"

Tags: ruby, cucumber, sinatra, calabash, calabash-android

For the purposes of testing. I have three computers running 9 containers locally on top of a ruby Sinatra server, testing an Android app. I'm using calabash server with cucumber steps.

All was running fine until about a month ago and I started seeing Calabash server errors. The first few containers run fine. Then it gets to around the 5th container and I start seeing a connection error as follow: "

```
 Error in Remote Calabash Server: 'Connection refused - Connection 
 refused - connect for "127.0.0.1" port 37265 (127.0.0.1:37265)'"
```

Followed by a long runtime error.

And that container craps out. The other containers will then usually run successfully after that.

I understand it's a very broad sounding issue and there's a lot of variables at play. But any suggestions at all of where to look would be most helpful. Could the servers just be struggling with too many requests? It's not getting hit by many at once, but who knows at this stage.

Any help as always much appreciated.

Comment: Also forgot to mention I am using Ngrok for port forwarding.